# Кастомная сортировка массива объектов разными методами

Tags: javascript, angular2

Делаю кастомную сортировку (по убыванию/возрастанию) данных в таблице.
Почему сортируется только в одну сторону? Обьект data меняется только один раз.

```
  data = [
    { name: "Вася", age: 23 },
    { name: "Маша", age: 18 },
    { name: "Вовочка", age: 6 }
  ];


  up() {
    let copy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.data))
    copy.sort(function (a, b) {
      return Number(a.age) + Number(b.age)
    })
    this.data = copy;
    console.log(this.data);
  }


  down() {
    let copy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.data))
    copy.sort(function (a, b) {
      return Number(a.age) - Number(b.age)
    })
    this.data = copy;
    console.log(this.data);
  }
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gcwe5p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш код должен иметь такой вид:

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {
  data = [
    { name: "Вася", age: 23 },
    { name: "Маша", age: 18 },
    { name: "Вовочка", age: 6 }
  ];



up() {
    let copy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.data))
    copy.sort(function (a, b) {
      return Number(a.age) - Number(b.age)
    })
    this.data = copy;
    console.log(this.data);
  }


  down() {
    let copy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.data))
    copy.sort(function (a, b) {
      return Number(b.age) - Number(a.age)
    })
    this.data = copy;
    console.log(this.data);
  }
}
```

**Разъяснения:**

В случае, если требуется сортировать элементы массива как числа (в порядку возрастания или убывания), или же сортировать их в каком-либо другом порядке, тогда Вы должны передать в `Array.sort()` свою собственную функцию как параметр. Эту функцию часто называют функцией сравнения. Функция сравнения должна принять 2 параметра и вернуть:

- отрицательное значение, если первый параметр `a` должен предшествовать второму `b` в отсортированном массиве;
- положительное значение, если второй параметр `b` должен предшествовать первому `a` в отсортированным массиве;
- 0, если оба параметра `a`,`b` являются равнозначными для процесса сортировки.

Таким образом функции сравнения чисел (по возрастанию или убыванию), должны иметь следующий вид :

**по возрастанию:**

```
function asort (a,b) {return a-b;}
```

**по убыванию:**

```
function asort(a,b) {return b-a;}
```